# Recommendation for a 64GB microSD card

Tags: data-storage, microsd

I want to order a 64GB microSD card.

I'm looking at the Samsung cards, because according to some reviews, they may offer slightly better performance than some other brands, like SanDisk.

The MB-M**P**64DA/AM has over [14,000 reviews on Amazon](http://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B00IVPU7AO), most of which are positive.  On Samsung's own website, the [reviews are rather dismal](http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/memory-storage-accessories/MB-MP64DA/AM).

On the other hand, the MB-M**C**64DA/AM [currently has only two useful Amazon reviews](http://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B01273JZMG), one negative and one positive.  The negative review claims that the write speed is horrible, and I don't know if that was just a measurement error.  On Samsung's own website, there are [currently no reviews](http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/memory-storage-accessories/MB-MC64DA/AM).

If I'm reading the specs correctly, the MB-M**C**64DA/AM *should be* the better card for high speed use.  It is classified as EVO+ instead of just EVO, but the specs on Samsung's website are very unclear.  For the MB-M**C**64DA/AM, Samsung claims "up to 80MB/s read" and "up to 20MB/s write", whereas for the MB-M**P**64DA/AM, Samsung claims "up to 48MB/s" (they don't break down read and write speeds for that card, making a comparison problematic).

Despite the fact that very few people seem to be buying it, would you recommend the MB-M**C**64DA/AM over the MB-M**P**64DA/AM?

Comment: There are some more reviews for the MC on amazon.co.uk, though they combine reviews for 32, 64, and 128GB.

Comment: You haven't written WHAT you want to use this card for. There is no such thing as "fastest" card, eg cards with higher (like 10) class are faster for large files (eg video) but for small files class 4 cards are the faster ones. This way or another, "performance" of a SD card is secondary issue, the big one is reliability. And because of that you should go for SanDisk or Lexar - if you have the money to burn.

Comment: @Agent_L Thanks! I have a sizable stack of genuine SanDisk cards that have gone bad.  I was not aware that Class 10 cards are faster for some things, but slower for others.  Can you expand on that here: http://superuser.com/questions/1013386/why-are-class-4-microsd-cards-faster-than-class-10-microsd-cards-for-small-files

Comment: I am going to say this question is opinion based, due to my, well, opinion based on experience, that the majority of SD cards, at least made by reputable manufacturers, tend to have about the same performance.  In the end, in my opinion the decision comes to capacity and price.

Comment: @NZKshatriya It's fine to have opinions, but yours - in this case - is not based on facts.  There is *significant* variability in SD card performance across different products.  Although, for you, the decision comes to capacity and price, others may find reliability and performance more important.

Comment: as you are looking for a 64GB microSD, that would fall under SDXC, as they range from >32GB to 2TB.  [TheWireCutter.com](http://thewirecutter.com/reviews/best-microsd-card/)  posted an article this year listing the EVO Plus as best for most peoples needs.....You still have not updated the question to list what you will be using the card for, remember that flash based memory has limited read/write, so they will degrade over time.